# LG Optimus Slider for tethering Kindle Fire

Tags: tethering, wifi-tethering, amazon-kindle-fire

I have rooted my LG Optimus Slider, and have downloaded several apps for tethering, however, none of them seems to be working with my Kindle Fire. I have read somewhere that the Kindle Fire does not accept ad-hoc signals from hotspots, which is what most of the tethering apps have. Is there a way to convert this signal to a format Kindle Fire will accept? Or, is there an app out there somewhere that would work better?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's possible your device's wifi chip or kernel doesn't support broadcasting in infrastructure mode (but I don't know anything about the Optimus Slider, so I couldn't say myself). Is the Fire rooted, or do you plan on rooting it? Might be possible that way.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out. :)

after getting my phone rooted, I found this link:

http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/downloads/detail?name=wifi_tether_v3_1-pre113.apk&can=2&q=label%3AExperimental

All you have to do is download that code in the link into your phone. It takes you to an app, and you install it. This is an experimental (beta) version of the app, which uses infrastructure wifi -the updated version uses ad hoc.

The beta version works great, and now I can get a great signal on my kindle fire from my phone, without having to root my kindle.

Answer (score 1):

This worked well for me aswell, but not real smooth.

Choosing the Optimus S from the "Change Device Profile" makes the HotSpot visible and works fine on the Kindle. There is an error associated with the app when the hotspot is started with this profile that is annoying at the worst. It appears this profile is attempting to start the built in OS Hotspot app which fails as we knew it would. In doing all that, it all works out.....

Thanks for the heads up. Will be pinging a few developers for a cleaner solution since the combo does work, just not very well with avail hotspot apps/tools.

Until then, FREE is still going to get a donation for providing me with "A" option.  ;)